# Determine same issuer from a list of ISINs?

Tags: fixed-income, finance

I have a list of ISINs for all the securities that make up a fixed-income fund. Is it possible to tell from this which securities are from the same issuer?

I have securities of which I know they are from the same issuer and part of the NSIN (the 9 digit code after the country code), the first 4 digits to be exact, are the same. What I couldn't figure is if this is a reliable identifier.

Comment: The ISIN contains within it a national identifier, when the country is US the national id is a CUSIP, and indeed 4 digits of CUSIP are the issuer code. But if the country is not US, those four digits could be anything, at least in theory.

Comment: Thank you.  So for each country there should be a unique identifier of a company? I googled it and for example Germany has a "Wertpapierkennnummer".

So I would run into an issue if the fund has securities from the same company issued in different countries because they would have different (national) identifiers, right?